# HTML file input control with capture and accept attributes

Tags: html, image, file, video, input

my code is:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*,video/*" capture>
```

When I test it on the Apple device and click on the input control, I open the camera and access the image and video.
But on Android, the "Choose an action" page appears, and the camera, camcorder, and documents are on the list.
I don't want it to show documents or pop-ups, and the user can't open folders.

i need image and video, this problem occurs when use accept="image/,video/"

Comment: my code:  <input type="file" accept="image/*,video/*" capture>

Comment: Do you really need both video and image? Selecting only one of these ( e.g `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>`) makes it open the CamCorder directly on my AndroPhone.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

OR

```
 <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="capture">
```

OR

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

Comment: i need image and video
when use 
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
or
<input type="file" accept="video/*" capture>
choose pop up do not show but when use
<input type="file" accept="image/*,video/*" capture>
it shown

Comment: Just split them into 2 buttons 1 for image and 1 for video

Answer (score 0):

Try using this,

```
 <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

```css
label.cameraButton {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em 0;

  /* Styles to make it look like a button */
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  border-color: #EEE #CCC #CCC #EEE;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

/* Look like a clicked/depressed button */
label.cameraButton:active {
  border-color: #CCC #EEE #EEE #CCC;
}

/* This is the part that actually hides the 'Choose file' text box for camera inputs */
label.cameraButton input[accept*="camera"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
  <label class="cameraButton">Take a picture
    <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
  </label>
```